# SVG - how to set text line-height

Tags: javascript, css, svg

It seems line-height is the one CSS property absent from svg text. The best resource on SVG I have found is: [Jenkov.com SVG Tutorials](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/text-element.html)  and there is no mention of it, neither [could I find mention of it on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=svg+line-height).

So if anyone can shed definitive light on this or share a technique. I am basically interested in the spacing between lines of text that wrap, not independent text elements.

Thanks

Comment: This might help but looks like a bit of a hack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857659/setting-line-height-for-text-element-in-raphael

Answer (score 16, accepted):

SVG 1.1 (officially) only supports single line text, hence no `line-height` setting.

I've just tried creating a block of text in Inkscape, and it's using a `flowRoot` element (containing a `flowPara` element with the actual text in it). Then the `flowRoot` element actually has `line-height` assigned to it (in %).

I don't know how wide-spread support for that way is, since [it used to be part of SVG 1.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-SVG12-20041027/flow.html). You might also want to have a look here: [Auto line-wrapping in SVG text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991171/auto-line-wrapping-in-svg-text)