# How to adjust line-height/ellipses in Highcharts axis labels

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there a way to adjust the line-height of axis labels in Highcharts? Sometimes with line-broken labels, overlap/spacing issues can occur that would be mitigated if it were possible to decrease line-height.

As you can see in the longer red labels in the image below, it would be helpful to customize line-height. Is there a way to do this? Setting `line-height` in either the CSS or in `xAxis.labels.style` did not have any effect.

### Example options:

```
xAxis: {
    labels: {
      style: { 
        textOverflow: 'none', // To disable automatic ellipsizing, per https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/3941
        // lineHeight: '0.5' // Has no effect
      }
    },
    categories: [
      'Sweden', 
      'Federal Democratic Republic of Ethiopia', 
      'Finland',
      'United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland', 
      'Oceania'],
 ...
```

#### Codepen: http://codepen.io/ericpedia/pen/peNZML

---

[image: Example of issue that could be resolved by customizing line-height]

Comment: line-height is not supported in css in svg. This is a property of html css, so you can try to enable [useHTML](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.useHTML) option and apply all the css options avaiable for HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this via css because there is no `line-height` presentational attribute support in svg. See the answer [svg-how-to-set-text-line-height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829277/svg-how-to-set-text-line-height). What Highcharts do - it mocks html-css `line-height` property on svg by setting [dy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dy) property. In SVG dy is not a presentational attribute so it cannot be set in stylesheet.

To preserve the lineheight option, you can modify Highcharts internal method so its cssish style will be applied.

```
var H = Highcharts;
H.wrap(H.Tick.prototype, 'addLabel', function (p) {
  p.call(this);

  const label = this.label;
  const labelOptions = this.axis.options.labels;

  if (label) {
    label.css({
      lineHeight: labelOptions.style.lineHeight
    })
  }
})
```

Axis config:

```
 labels: {
      style: { 
        textOverflow: 'none',
        lineHeight: 12
      }
    },
```

#### Live example and output:

https://jsfiddle.net/4dztcw5d/

[image: lineheight]

As I mentioned in the comment, you can also set [labels.useHTML](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.useHTML) to true, build a proper html and apply to it html-css styling, including line-height.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the highcharts library that you are using doesn't take into account some of the css.
I tried using this one http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js and seems to work i added in the x-axis label style

```
 fontSize:'15px',
 lineHeight: "12"
```

and had to set the colors with !important

```
text:nth-child(odd){ fill: blue!important; }
text:nth-child(even){ fill: red!important; }
```

and it seems to work, here is the codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ryWoxo

Comment: Noted. However, I'm looking for a way to do this with the CSS "[styled mode](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css)" branch of Highcharts, which is probably why we are getting different results. 

Interestingly, in the JS-styled branch you are using, it appears to convert any `style.lineHeight` value, regardless of units, into a number of pixels, as opposed to permitting the values permitted by the [CSS line-height spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height).