# Highcharts - how to set line height in multiline annotations labels in styled mode

Tags: highcharts

Hello Highcharts team!

Qq - I am trying to set line height for multiline annotation in styled mode i.e. set a `dy`. I know that in non-styled mode it's achieved by setting annotations[0].labels[0].style.lineHeight property [docs](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations.labels.style), but having trouble with  how to do that in styled mode. useHTML wont work for me because we utilize exporting module and seems like line breaks are not preserved in downloaded images/svg when useHTML is enabled.
Link to fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/4vrgysxk/1/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best approach is:

- set `useHTML` as true for the annotation label,
- render annotation as HTML element and style it,
- set the `exporting.allowHTML` as true,

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wp3rqmge/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.allowHTML

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations.labelOptions.useHTML

Comment: Thanks Sebastian! Our charts a bit more complicated and unfortunately the solution you proposed doesn't work for us. I was hoping to modify Highcharts internal method like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42663155/how-to-adjust-line-height-ellipses-in-highcharts-axis-labels/42678647#42678647) answer with styling Ticks. Is there a similar method for annotation labels?

Comment: @Sabira what is wrong with this solution?

Comment: when SVG is placed into illustrator the annotation label text is invisible

Comment: What kind of illustrator do you test? Have you tested any other text colors for the annotation?

Comment: I am using Adobe Illustrator v24.2.1, yes I've tested with other colors.

Comment: I have a custom logic in place, but wanted to know if there is an internal method I can use, similar to 

```
var H = Highcharts;
H.wrap(H.Tick.prototype, 'addLabel', function (p) {
  p.call(this);

  const label = this.label;
  const labelOptions = this.axis.options.labels;

  if (label) {
    label.css({
      lineHeight: labelOptions.style.lineHeight
    })
  }
}).
```

 If there isn't I'll stick to that custom code I have.